# C++ Eigen execution time difference

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen, clang++, execution-time

So I'm calculating a lot of statistical distances in my application, written in C++ (11/14). I use the Eigen library for linear algebra calculations. My code was initially compiled on macOS, particularly BigSur. Since I need to make my results reproducible, I was trying to get the same results under other OS, particularly Fedora 32. However, there are significant result differences, which I cannot contribute to anything specific after trying various things.

So I made a sample code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  MatrixXd cov(2,2);
  cov << 1.5,0.2,0.2,1.5;
  VectorXd mean(2),ne(2);
  mean << 10,10;
  ne << 10.2,10.2;
  
  auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i=0;i<2000000;i++) {
    MatrixXd icov=cov.inverse();
    VectorXd delta=ne-mean;
    double N0=delta.transpose()*(icov*delta);
    double res=sqrtf(N0);
  }
  auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
  
  cout << "Mahalanobis calculations in "
       << duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count()
       << " ms." << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

which was compiled with

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -w -O2 -I'....Eigen/include' -DNDEBUG -m64 -o benchmark benchmark.cpp
```

on both, macOS and Fedora32. Yes, I downloaded and installed clang on Fedora, just to be sure I'm using the same compiler. On macOS, I have clang version 12.0.0, and on Fedora 10.0.1!

The difference between these test cases is 2x

macOS:

```
Mahalanobis calculations in 2833 ms.
```

Fedora:

```
Mahalanobis calculations in 1490 ms.
```

When it comes to my specific application, the difference is almost 30x, which is quite unusual. In the meantime I checked for the following:

- OpenMP support - tried switching on and off, compile time and runtime (setting the number of threads before the test code chunk)
- various compiling flags and architectures
- adding OpenMP support to macOS
- tempering with EIGEN_USE_BLAS, EIGEN_USE_LAPACKE, and EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE flags

Nothing helps. Any ideas where is the problem?
Maybe something with memory management?

Comment: Can you add the C++ runtimes are you linking against to the question (and what version)?

Comment: macOS: libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib, Fedora: libstdc++.so.6.0.28, Eigen 3.3.4

Comment: Your code likely spends most of the time with allocating/deallocating memory. Try replacing `MatrixXd` with `Matrix2d` and `VectorXd` by `Vector2d`.

Comment: Performance result questions are difficulty to answer, particularly if your question is strictly focused on understanding a difference between two binaries. I assume you were running on the same hardware? Have you check the assembly output for the two compiles?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, to answer the question for all those that encounter the same problem. The issue is in the memory management. As someone pointed out, these is a big difference between dynamically and statically allocated Eigen objects. So

```
MatrixXd cov(2,2);
```

tends to be much slower than

```
Matrix<double,2,2> cov;
```

since the first approach uses heap to dynamically allocate the needed memory. At the end of the day, it all comes down to the way how the OS handles memory. It seems that Linux is doing it better than macOS or Windows (no surprises there actually).

I know that it is not possible always to use `Matrix2d` over the good old `MatrixXd`. Some developers even reported that Eigen matrix math tends to be slower than their own home-made simple solutions, but this comes down to the choice of doing everything yourself, or taking all-purpose linera algebra library. Depends on what you are doing...